# Name of Book, Atlantean girl next door?

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel, atlantis

I am trying to find the name of a book I read as a child and thought people here might know.

**Plot -** The plot is basically that the girl who lives next door to the protagonist is weird and can 'float for joy' - that is, levitate. She turns out to be a descendant of Atlantis or something similar - an elder race in decline now living discretely amongst humans. They cannot interbreed - at one point the Atlanteans are described analogously to horses and humans akin to donkeys. The result is something like a mule.

I think it might have been hazardous for the humans and the others to touch? Painful?

Additional Details -

**Media -** Single Book / Novel

**Date of Publication -** Pretty sure it was in either a children's section of a public library or a school library and it pre-dates 1995. Might even pre-date 1988.

**Major Themes -** decline of a race / empire?

**Tone -** a children's book but otherwise I cannot really remember.

**Characters -** two children, one human one otherwise. However, cannot remember if the protagonist was male or female?

**Language** - The book was in English and I read it in England.

**Target Audience -** Older children? Teens?

Comment: When were you a child? Did it look recent? Was the book in English? How many pages? Illustrations? Anything distinctive about the cover? Paperback or hardback? Scholastic book fair find?

Comment: Please check out https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/23243 for more details to add to your question.

Comment: Possibly one of Zemma Henderson's [The People](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ingathering:_The_Complete_People_Stories) series?

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I had a look but no it is not 'The People'. Pretty sure they were not aliens but of earthly origin.